# Can PHPword show Pie Chart in percenage with two decimals?

Tags: php, phpword

I use [PHPword](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) class to create Word file in PHP.

Can you create Pie chart to show value in percentage with two decimals?

```
  $c3 = array('Expensive kW', 'Cheap kW');
  $s3 = array($expensive, $cheap);

  $tablePie2Charts = $section->addTable('Chart');
  $tablePie2Charts->addRow();

  $stylePie2Chart = array(
    'width' => Converter::inchToEmu(5),
    'height' => Converter::inchToEmu(3),
    'valueAxisTitle' => 'Last month consumed in kW',
    'showLegend' => true,
    'dataLabelOptions' => array(
      'showCatName' => false,
      'showVal' => false,
      'showPercent' => true
    )
  );

  $c1 = $tablePie2Charts->addCell()->addChart('pie', $c3, $s3, $stylePie2Chart);
```

Comment: Please provide what you've tried

Comment: Question is updated. This code created pie chart but not percenage with two decimals. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem.But i can't find an api to support it.
And here my solution:
edit the file /PhpOffice/Phpword/Writer/Word2007/Part/Chart.php

near the line 250. Insert the code

`$xmlWriter->writeElementBlock("c:numFmt",['formatCode'=>'0.00%','sourceLinked'=>'0']);`

between

`$xmlWriter->startElement('c:dLbls');`

and

`foreach ($style->getDataLabelOptions() as $option => $val) {`

It finally look like that:

`$xmlWriter->startElement('c:dLbls');
$xmlWriter->writeElementBlock("c:numFmt",['formatCode'=>'0.00%','sourceLinked'=>'0']);
foreach ($style->getDataLabelOptions() as $option => $val)`

if you just want it in pie chart and you should:

`if ('pie' === $this->element->getType()){
                $xmlWriter->writeElementBlock("c:numFmt",['formatCode'=>'0.00%','sourceLinked'=>'0']);
            }`

You can change the formatCode like 0.0% 0.00% 0.000% whatever you want.

If someone find the better way,plz tell me,thanks.